# How to include special characters in Crystal report as a literal string?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I am having a problem to find a way to include special character in the Crystal report as a literal string.
and I want to have a code that will help me fix any special character I want. Any Help would be appreciated.

I know a little bit about Replace function but I need a correct structure to use it.

Comment: Please provide more detail. 
Example of special character? Displayed on a Crystal report as what: text object? database field? Formula field?  Font?  Why doesn't it display properly now?